# Error trying to unit test Mongoose schema validation with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I'm new to Jest and try to set up a simple test script:

```
"use strict"

// Local dependencies
const userModel = require('./user.model');

// Setting controllers
describe("Users endpoint", () => {
    describe("Validating user schema", () => {
        it("Should return an error if name property is missing", () => {
            const user = new userModel();

            user.validate((error) => {
                expect(error.errors.name.kind).toBe("required");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

When running Jest, I got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Identifier 'global' has already been declared

  2 |
  3 | // Local dependencies
> 4 | const userModel = require('./user.model');
```

I search on Google and didn't find anything related to the 'global' identifier.

Any help would be really appreciate.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: What is your jest setup? It might be looking in another folder by default ...

Comment: @Akrion, Does this line " FAIL web/api/user/user.test.js" confirm that jest is looking at the right place? I even try to add testRegex and then testMatch without success. I have the default config generated by --init with a node environment.

Comment: @Akrion, And the error seem to point to the "required(." part.

Comment: `const userModel = require('./user.model')` should that be `const userModel = require('./user/model')`.

Comment: @Akrion, not it's because my file name is user.model.js. But I just try by removing the "require" statement and all references to userModel and the test passed. So the issue seems to be with the "require".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after digging a bit more, I figured out that the issue was with a const global inside my require script:

```
const global = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'config', 'config'));
```

If I change the "global" name for anything else (i.e. globalTest), it will works.

Sousing  "global" seems to be not allowed.